# CSS, fixed clip of content but not background

Tags: css, svg, css-position

I have a setup like this:

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
 z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  background-image: url('http://img04.deviantart.net/c00a/i/2013/020/7/e/w__disney_texture_stock_by_redwolf518stock-d5s70kx.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>My profile</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>
      Title
    </h1>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne mel integre disputationi delicatissimi, per quando populo iudicabit eu. Qui ea copiosae lucilius. Meis minimum usu ea. Ut has quis nostro conceptam, eu vel hinc nostrum nominati. Vel at nominati maluisset, ne quando populo nostrum nec, et est nulla temporibus. No sit bonorum luptatum, affert scripta tincidunt ex usu. Ei homero scaevola torquatos sed, pri dolore commune reprehendunt ex, moderatius temporibus his ei.</p>

<p>In dicam iudico his, vel cu latine graecis, ei justo vidisse intellegebat vel. Ex vel dicat errem. Vim ea ornatus expetendis efficiantur, feugiat debitis appetere vis cu. Ius utroque inciderint reprehendunt no, ei homero persius patrioque vis. In eirmod discere nominavi vel. Oblique mediocritatem no mei, perpetua adversarium pri ex.</p>

<p>Eius omnis prompta no usu, probatus persecuti dissentiet et qui, qui albucius molestie at. Partem splendide nam et, adhuc denique sed ad. Eos at odio fabellas tractatos. Saepe aeterno sit ex.</p>

<p>Usu ut putent animal appetere. Suas eius idque ut sea. Te ius nisl definitionem. Nam esse alterum deleniti ei, usu in assueverit referrentur. Ut purto simul mucius eum.</p>

<p>Mel ne ceteros apeirian scriptorem. Id augue omnes dicam vix, sed atqui vidisse legendos ex. Scriptorem persequeris disputationi vel ei, novum adolescens quo ex. Quaeque efficiantur eum ei. Et has decore appellantur, option similique contentiones an pro.</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne mel integre disputationi delicatissimi, per quando populo iudicabit eu. Qui ea copiosae lucilius. Meis minimum usu ea. Ut has quis nostro conceptam, eu vel hinc nostrum nominati. Vel at nominati maluisset, ne quando populo nostrum nec, et est nulla temporibus. No sit bonorum luptatum, affert scripta tincidunt ex usu. Ei homero scaevola torquatos sed, pri dolore commune reprehendunt ex, moderatius temporibus his ei.</p>

<p>In dicam iudico his, vel cu latine graecis, ei justo vidisse intellegebat vel. Ex vel dicat errem. Vim ea ornatus expetendis efficiantur, feugiat debitis appetere vis cu. Ius utroque inciderint reprehendunt no, ei homero persius patrioque vis. In eirmod discere nominavi vel. Oblique mediocritatem no mei, perpetua adversarium pri ex.</p>

<p>Eius omnis prompta no usu, probatus persecuti dissentiet et qui, qui albucius molestie at. Partem splendide nam et, adhuc denique sed ad. Eos at odio fabellas tractatos. Saepe aeterno sit ex.</p>

<p>Usu ut putent animal appetere. Suas eius idque ut sea. Te ius nisl definitionem. Nam esse alterum deleniti ei, usu in assueverit referrentur. Ut purto simul mucius eum.</p>

<p>Mel ne ceteros apeirian scriptorem. Id augue omnes dicam vix, sed atqui vidisse legendos ex. Scriptorem persequeris disputationi vel ei, novum adolescens quo ex. Quaeque efficiantur eum ei. Et has decore appellantur, option similique contentiones an pro.</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne mel integre disputationi delicatissimi, per quando populo iudicabit eu. Qui ea copiosae lucilius. Meis minimum usu ea. Ut has quis nostro conceptam, eu vel hinc nostrum nominati. Vel at nominati maluisset, ne quando populo nostrum nec, et est nulla temporibus. No sit bonorum luptatum, affert scripta tincidunt ex usu. Ei homero scaevola torquatos sed, pri dolore commune reprehendunt ex, moderatius temporibus his ei.</p>

<p>In dicam iudico his, vel cu latine graecis, ei justo vidisse intellegebat vel. Ex vel dicat errem. Vim ea ornatus expetendis efficiantur, feugiat debitis appetere vis cu. Ius utroque inciderint reprehendunt no, ei homero persius patrioque vis. In eirmod discere nominavi vel. Oblique mediocritatem no mei, perpetua adversarium pri ex.</p>

<p>Eius omnis prompta no usu, probatus persecuti dissentiet et qui, qui albucius molestie at. Partem splendide nam et, adhuc denique sed ad. Eos at odio fabellas tractatos. Saepe aeterno sit ex.</p>

<p>Usu ut putent animal appetere. Suas eius idque ut sea. Te ius nisl definitionem. Nam esse alterum deleniti ei, usu in assueverit referrentur. Ut purto simul mucius eum.</p>

<p>Mel ne ceteros apeirian scriptorem. Id augue omnes dicam vix, sed atqui vidisse legendos ex. Scriptorem persequeris disputationi vel ei, novum adolescens quo ex. Quaeque efficiantur eum ei. Et has decore appellantur, option similique contentiones an pro.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, there is a fixed header with transparent background and some content with an image background.

I'd like to achieve the following effect: as the content scrolls up underneath the header, the text should be clipped, as if going behind an invisible wall, but the background should remain visible.

[image]

I tried adding a `clip-path` property to the `.content`, and referencing a fixed-positioned svg, but I just couldn't find a combination that worked.

Anyone has any (other) ideas?

I guess I could always position a background image using javascript, but that will probably be kind of janky. CSS-only solution would be the best.

I'd be OK with a solutions that only works in Chrome (targeting electron).

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or similar

Comment: Click "Run code snippet" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses [`mix-blend-mode: screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). You should arrange everything in the following layers:

1. The header
2. The background overlay. The overlay should have `mix-blend-mode: screen` that blocks black content, but shows white content. The overlay should have `pointer-events: none` to enable interaction with the content under it.
3. The header background. An area with black background that will hide the text. I've used a gradient to soften the text disappearance.
4. The text.

The overlay covers everything, but the header. The white text is shown, but the black header background is not, and so is the text under the header background.

```css
body {
    position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px
}

.header, .header-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.header {
  z-index: 3;
}

.header-bg {
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 75%, transparent 100%);
}

.content {
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background-image: url('http://img04.deviantart.net/c00a/i/2013/020/7/e/w__disney_texture_stock_by_redwolf518stock-d5s70kx.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  background-color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  pointer-events: none;

}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header-bg"></div>

  <div class="header">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>My profile</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <h1>
      Title
    </h1>
    <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne mel integre disputationi delicatissimi, per quando populo iudicabit eu. Qui ea copiosae lucilius. Meis minimum usu ea. Ut has quis nostro conceptam, eu vel hinc nostrum nominati. Vel at nominati maluisset, ne quando populo nostrum nec, et est nulla temporibus. No sit bonorum luptatum, affert scripta tincidunt ex usu. Ei homero scaevola torquatos sed, pri dolore commune reprehendunt ex, moderatius temporibus his ei.</p>

<p>In dicam iudico his, vel cu latine graecis, ei justo vidisse intellegebat vel. Ex vel dicat errem. Vim ea ornatus expetendis efficiantur, feugiat debitis appetere vis cu. Ius utroque inciderint reprehendunt no, ei homero persius patrioque vis. In eirmod discere nominavi vel. Oblique mediocritatem no mei, perpetua adversarium pri ex.</p>

<p>Eius omnis prompta no usu, probatus persecuti dissentiet et qui, qui albucius molestie at. Partem splendide nam et, adhuc denique sed ad. Eos at odio fabellas tractatos. Saepe aeterno sit ex.</p>

<p>Usu ut putent animal appetere. Suas eius idque ut sea. Te ius nisl definitionem. Nam esse alterum deleniti ei, usu in assueverit referrentur. Ut purto simul mucius eum.</p>

<p>Mel ne ceteros apeirian scriptorem. Id augue omnes dicam vix, sed atqui vidisse legendos ex. Scriptorem persequeris disputationi vel ei, novum adolescens quo ex. Quaeque efficiantur eum ei. Et has decore appellantur, option similique contentiones an pro.</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne mel integre disputationi delicatissimi, per quando populo iudicabit eu. Qui ea copiosae lucilius. Meis minimum usu ea. Ut has quis nostro conceptam, eu vel hinc nostrum nominati. Vel at nominati maluisset, ne quando populo nostrum nec, et est nulla temporibus. No sit bonorum luptatum, affert scripta tincidunt ex usu. Ei homero scaevola torquatos sed, pri dolore commune reprehendunt ex, moderatius temporibus his ei.</p>

<p>In dicam iudico his, vel cu latine graecis, ei justo vidisse intellegebat vel. Ex vel dicat errem. Vim ea ornatus expetendis efficiantur, feugiat debitis appetere vis cu. Ius utroque inciderint reprehendunt no, ei homero persius patrioque vis. In eirmod discere nominavi vel. Oblique mediocritatem no mei, perpetua adversarium pri ex.</p>

<p>Eius omnis prompta no usu, probatus persecuti dissentiet et qui, qui albucius molestie at. Partem splendide nam et, adhuc denique sed ad. Eos at odio fabellas tractatos. Saepe aeterno sit ex.</p>

<p>Usu ut putent animal appetere. Suas eius idque ut sea. Te ius nisl definitionem. Nam esse alterum deleniti ei, usu in assueverit referrentur. Ut purto simul mucius eum.</p>

<p>Mel ne ceteros apeirian scriptorem. Id augue omnes dicam vix, sed atqui vidisse legendos ex. Scriptorem persequeris disputationi vel ei, novum adolescens quo ex. Quaeque efficiantur eum ei. Et has decore appellantur, option similique contentiones an pro.</p>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne mel integre disputationi delicatissimi, per quando populo iudicabit eu. Qui ea copiosae lucilius. Meis minimum usu ea. Ut has quis nostro conceptam, eu vel hinc nostrum nominati. Vel at nominati maluisset, ne quando populo nostrum nec, et est nulla temporibus. No sit bonorum luptatum, affert scripta tincidunt ex usu. Ei homero scaevola torquatos sed, pri dolore commune reprehendunt ex, moderatius temporibus his ei.</p>

<p>In dicam iudico his, vel cu latine graecis, ei justo vidisse intellegebat vel. Ex vel dicat errem. Vim ea ornatus expetendis efficiantur, feugiat debitis appetere vis cu. Ius utroque inciderint reprehendunt no, ei homero persius patrioque vis. In eirmod discere nominavi vel. Oblique mediocritatem no mei, perpetua adversarium pri ex.</p>

<p>Eius omnis prompta no usu, probatus persecuti dissentiet et qui, qui albucius molestie at. Partem splendide nam et, adhuc denique sed ad. Eos at odio fabellas tractatos. Saepe aeterno sit ex.</p>

<p>Usu ut putent animal appetere. Suas eius idque ut sea. Te ius nisl definitionem. Nam esse alterum deleniti ei, usu in assueverit referrentur. Ut purto simul mucius eum.</p>

<p>Mel ne ceteros apeirian scriptorem. Id augue omnes dicam vix, sed atqui vidisse legendos ex. Scriptorem persequeris disputationi vel ei, novum adolescens quo ex. Quaeque efficiantur eum ei. Et has decore appellantur, option similique contentiones an pro.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great in the example, but in my real code, it's not quite right. In actuality, I have images and other content besides the text. So everything gets a slight shade. However, since you solved the problem as posed, I'll mark it as solved. Very interesting idea with overlays.

Comment: That's a pity. That was an interesting question.